# Where is "from" imported from camel in java?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to import csv file to xml file

i see apache has feature to do

```
    from(in)
            .to(out)
                .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
                .unmarshal().csv();
```

but i have a "cannot resolve method 'from(java.lang.String)' error

when I try to import then i cannot find any packages for camel

this one works:

```
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat;
```

what is the package to use "from" from org.apache.camel.???

this is my file:

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.BindyAbstractDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.BindyAbstractFactory;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.BindyFixedLengthFactory;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.FormatFactory;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.util.ConverterUtils;
import org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper;
import org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Message;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;


public class Csvtoxml {

    public static void convert(String in, String out) throws Exception {
        DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(Model.class);

        from("myCsvFile.csv")
            .to("myXmlFile.xml")
                .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
                .unmarshal().csv();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not imported from anywhere. In order to use it this way you have to inherit your class from `org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder`

Comment: the "from" is still red after adding this to the top of the file

Comment: One more time "In order to use it this way you have to inherit your class from org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder". So you have to extend your class like this `public class YourClass extends RouteBuilder`. Then you will be able to use `from` inside `YourClass`